# MINUS vs NOT in where clause

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a query which retrieves data from a single table.  However the query uses the `MINUS` clause like this:

```
SELECT field1, field2
FROM tab
WHERE field3 = 'a'
AND field4 = 'b'
    MINUS
SELECT field1, field2
FROM tab
WHERE field5 = 'c'
AND field6 = 'd'
```

Since this is selecting from the same table I am trying to rewrite this to get rid of the `MINUS` clause.  I thought that something like this should work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT field1, field2
FROM tab
WHERE field3 = 'a'
AND field4 = 'b'
AND NOT (field5 = 'c'
AND field6 = 'd')
```

My reasoning is that if the `MINUS` clause excludes records in the second query, then wrapping the `WHERE` clause in an `AND NOT` should get rid of the same records.  The `MINUS` clause also gets rid of duplicates which is why I added `DISTINCT` to the selection.  However the problem is that my query is returning *more* records than the original.

What am I missing here?

Comment: The second query is only checking an individual row. The WHERE clause ais applied to each separate row being accessed. There's no reference to check for the non-existence of *other* rows in the table. The normative approaches to obtaining the type of result returned by the first query is a set based operator (the MINUS set operation), a NOT EXISTS predicate with a correlated subquery, or an anti-join pattern. To get the same collapsing behavior of the MINUS set operator, we'd need to add a GROUP BY clause. Another approach requiring the GROUP BY is a HAVING check on an aggregate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider these two rows:

1, 2, a, b, x, y

1, 2, u, v, c, d

The MINUS operation will not return the pair (1, 2) but your query will. The c, d values may appear with the same 1, 2 but in a different row from the a, b

The fundamental distinction is that MINUS operates at the set level, while your NOT condition only works on one row at a time (the same row with the "required" values in the other columns).

Now: You CAN make your query a bit more efficient (although you can't avoid reading the base table twice). Use a NOT IN condition:

```
select field1, field2 from tab where field3 = 'a' and field4 = 'b'
and    (field1, field2) not in 
           (select field1, field2 from tab where field5 = 'c' and field6 = 'd');
```

**Note** (see spencer7593's comment below): As in all cases when NULLs may be present, NOT IN is not a good solution. Rather, a NOT EXISTS condition should be used. I won't elaborate, since it seems out of scope for the question asked (which was why the "NOT" solution is different from the "MINUS" solution).

Comment: Beware of the subquery returning NULL values for field1 and field2. Consider how the NOT IN evaluates after we do something this: `INSERT INTO tab (field1,field2,field5,field6) VALUES (NULL,NULL,'c','d')`.

Comment: @spencer7593 - Of course. I will add a note to explain.

Comment: As I showed in my answer, there is no need to read the base table twice.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz - Right. I should have said it differently: "although this way you don't avoid reading the base table twice." The grouping solution you provided (and Spencer mentioned in a Comment to the original post) is superior to mine. I was more focused on the OP's question, which is "why does his second query produce more results than the MINUS solution" - but for the best solution he should look at your Answer. (Actually what I posted doesn't even DISTINCT the results, so it's not exactly what the OP wanted anyway.)

Comment: Just for the records - my solution preceded the comment by 25 minutes :-)

Answer (score 2):

In this solutions the table is being referenced only once.

```
select      field1,field2

from        tab

where       (field3,field4) in (('a','b'))
        or  (field5,field6) in (('c','d'))

group by    field1,field2

having      max(case when (field5,field6) in (('c','d')) then 1 else 0 end) = 0
;
```

OR

```
select      field1,field2

from        tab

group by    field1,field2

having      max(case when (field3,field4) in (('a','b')) then 1 else 0 end) = 1
        and max(case when (field5,field6) in (('c','d')) then 1 else 0 end) = 0
;
```

Comment: This is probably more efficient than using `select distinct` with the set operator.

Comment: DISTINCT cannot be used here because of the HAVING logic.P.s. I would expect GROUP BY and DISTINCT to have the same implementation and performance.

Comment: . . I was referring to `select distinct` in the original question.